# How to use comparison between values in Redis and Result one details?

Tags: linux, redis, in-memory-database, key-value-store

I want store the below structure details in redis. I thought of using redis `HASH`.

Structure:

```
Id   HighRange   LowRange    Data1   Data2
1    11222000    11222999    some    text
2    22333000    22333999    some    text
```

I want to check particular range value is present or not. If it is present I have to get all corresponding details from structure.

If this is a Database table, I would use `'11222456' >= HighRange and '11222456' <= LowRange`. But, I don't know how to store these structure into Redis. So that I can search in the Redis by using in between range value.

I did googling, I found `ZRANGE`, `ZRANGEBYSCORE`. But, these are not fit my needs.

Kindly guide me, How to handle like this pattern in Redis.

Comment: Each `row` contain both High and Low range score?

Comment: Yes..High and low range value are in same row .

Comment: Consider upvoting/accepting @h0x91B answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you need a https://redis.io/topics/indexes#multi-dimensional-indexes

This technique allows you to make indexes for two or more dimensions, like XYZ. Little bit complicated to understand, but lets try.

Lets say that your LowRange is X and HighRange is Y
And our data is looks like this:

```
ID  X    Y
1   0100 0200
2   0150 0250
3   0200 0270
4   0180 0250
```

We make ZSET and use **same** `SCORE` for each row, but our value is interleaved value:

```
ZADD ZSET:1 0 00120000:1
ZADD ZSET:1 0 00125500:2
ZADD ZSET:1 0 00220700:3
ZADD ZSET:1 0 00128500:4
```

When we give same `SCORE` redis do lexical sorting based on value.

Interleaved value... For example we have `abc` and `xyz` as values and we want to interleave them, first of all we **must** make padding, so our `abc` now will be `0abc` and `xyz` is now `0xyz` if we have padding for 4 chars of course.

Then we take first char from left side of padded value 1 and add first char of value 2, then second char, third etc... Result is `00axbycz`.

So, interleaved value of X `0100` Y `0200` is `00120000`, so our ZSET value is `<interleavedXY>:<ID>`

Now we can make searches like `x >= 120 && x < 200 && y >= 220 && y < 270` using ZRANGEBYLEX command (https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex)

```
ZRANGEBYLEX ZSET:1 [00122200 [00220700
```

The result will be:

```
1) "00125500:2"
2) "00128500:4"
```

We found entry 2 and 4.

We will still need to check outbound of our search in code, but it gives very good results.